# Is there any way to migrate existing java+appium project into robotframework+appium project?

Tags: java, mobile, automation, appium, robotframework

I have an existing project based on java+appium+selenium+testNG. 
Is there any way to migrate existing test cases to robotframework+appium?
Rewriting all existing (maybe 300) test cases is not an option.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

The big warning I'd give is that RobotFramework's Appium library is not being actively maintained, and has notable bugs in it (for example, Click Button doesn't return a recognizable error when the element cannot be found).  As such, I would strongly advise against trying this in the first place.

But to your general question, the only way to do that would be to use your existing tests as a Library in RobotFramework, then call them with the appropriate names.  So if you had a test that was called by the function loginToServer(), you'd call "Login To Server" in Robot.  However, that would lose the majority of the point of Robot (since the reporting would only show the one step, and not the remaining steps of your test), and would thus be pretty pointless.